# JDB stops on every exception - how to prevent this

Tags: java, jdb

I am using a jdb dubugger, and the problem with it that is stops on every caught exception, though I did not execute any catch .... statements. During class loading there are hundreds of them:

> Exception occurred: java.io.FileNotFoundException
>   (uncaught)"thread=Thread-2-EmulatorEngine",
>   sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(), line=634 bci=30

Is it any way to instruct jdb to skip these exceptions ?

PS. I have heard about IDE editors of cause. Have reasons to use jdb.

Comment: Typically it only does this if the exception isn't going to be caught, so java is going to exit otherwise. These are exceptions that are caught somewhere?

Comment: No, java does not exit in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized that I am not careful enough. JDB writes after launch these lines

> Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
>
> Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable

So, to disable that, I need to enter a command

```
ignore uncaught java.lang.Throwable
```

Comment: Not found: uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Usage: ignore [uncaught|caught|all] <class id>|<class pattern>
When running jdb App.class, would anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

If you're having the same issue as me, you need to use the fully qualified name of the class when defining the break point.

Example - Set break point in main method:
stop in com.foo.bar.App.main

It may be that you are trying to set a break point for a class file different than the one you are debugging (which probably doesn't exist).